# Получить данные из базы если они не принадлежат к определенной категории

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с категориями

```
id | parentid | name    
1  | 0        | Куртки
2  | 1        | Фирма А  
3  | 1        | Фирма Б 
4  | 0        | Джинсы 
5  | 4        | Фирма А   
6  | 4        | Фирма Б   
7  | 0        | Распродажи
```

Так же есть таблица с товарами

```
id | name    
1  | Товар 1
2  | Товар 2 
3  | Товар 3 
4  | Товар 4
5  | Товар 5   
6  | Товар 6 
7  | Товар 7
```

И таблица которая связывает товар с категориями

```
id | prod_id  | cat_id    
1  | 2        | 2
2  | 2        | 3 
3  | 2        | 7
4  | 3        | 5 
5  | 3        | 6   
6  | 5        | 2  
7  | 6        | 5
```

Необходимо выбрать товары из базы которые не принадлежат к категории Распродажи (ID 7). То есть в выборку должны попасть любые товары кроме товара Товар 2 (ID 2) так как он относится к категории Распродажи (ID 7).
Получается так, что товар может иметь отношения к любым категория (к нескольким сразу), но в выборку товар дожен попадать если у него нет категории Распродажи (ID 7).

Подскажите каким образом можно получить нужные данные из базы?

Comment: SELECT * FROM products as p 
JOIN product_categories as cp on p.id = cp.prod_id
JOIN categories as c ON c.id = cp.cat_id
WHERE c.id != 7  

Соединяешь таблицы по ключам и в условии пишешь что категория не должна быть 7ой

Comment: Это бы работало если бы у товара была одна категория, но у товара их может быть много и задача именно убрать полностью товар из выборки если он есть в категории Распродажи (ID 7).

Comment: SELECT * FROM Products as p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_categories as pc where pc.cat_id= 7 and pc.prod_id = p.id) в таком случае попробуйте так, и вообще, хотелось бы увидеть ваши попытки написать запрос )